# How to make the home page of my app dynamic?

Tags: node.js, websocket, grpc

I have an app with backend written in node.js and app written in dart(flutter).
We tend to display feeds on the homepage. But the user doesn't see the latest feeds until a manual refresh is done.
How can I prevent this manual refresh.

Currently we have a rest api in place which is called on the refresh.
Will sending a socket event help or should I use gRPC server streaming.

Comment: send socket event from server, receive it in frontend, and make according refreshes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.